# How to make xterm command line works like vim

Tags: linux, vim, command, xterm

I'm working on RHEL environment, and using xterm.

My question is that how to make the xterm command line works like vim instead of emacs (eg, selection, copy, paste, keyboard shortcuts)

Thanks!

Comment: `xterm` has nothing to do with this. You're looking for a feature of your shell, which means you should tell us which shell you're using (likely bash).

Answer (score 3):

The bash command to turn on vim-style editing is

```
set -o vi
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned, this has nothing to do with the terminal(emulator) you're using. In case you use zsh, you can enable vi-like bindings with:

```
bindkey -v
```

Answer (score 0):

The Emacs-style keybindings to which you are referring are actually a feature of the [Readline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readline) utility.

While adding, `set -o vi` to the end of your `~/.bash_profile` should suffice (if you're a bash user), this utility can also be controlled through the use of an `~/.inputrc` file.

Create an `~/.inputrc` if it doesn't already exist and append this:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command
```

The benefit of this approach over `set -o vi` is that this is read wherever readline is used include the MySQL command line interface and Ruby's IRB.

See this post for more Vim-related readline tips:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal

Comment: This is only true if the shell uses readline.  `zsh`, for example, doesn't.